# How to display scalar value in post from a custom table created in Wordpress DB?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve a varchar value from my WordPress DB. I tried the following code without success. Also tried with `get_results` instead of `get_row`, my post just shows the HTML code without the "brand" value (PHP snippets are enabled). How can I show a scalar value from my DB in my posts, index..? Do I need to set up a connection again?

```
<?php
      $db_brand = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT brand FROM $wpdb->brands where id = 1" );
      echo "<p>The brand in this post is {$db_brand}</p>";    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you get row, but need show column. use

```
<?php
      $db_brand = (array)$wpdb->get_row( "SELECT brand FROM $wpdb->brands where id = 1" );
      echo "<p>The brand in this post is {$db_brand['brand']}</p>";    
?>
```

Comment: Hello Evgeniy, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but it keeps no working.

Comment: I think you need write table, from you want select value. Maybe $wpdb->brands does not contains table name.